# Statistic data on average morpheme-to-word ratios

Tags: turkish, agglutination, dravidian, agglutinative-languages, tamil

I wonder whether there is any statistic data on morpheme-to-word ratio of certain languages. Is this something that can be and has been measured? The languages I am most interested in are the agglutinative languages Tamil and Turkish.

Could further an average morpheme-to-word ratio be justifiably called a *constant* of a given language, at least in a small timeframe?

How about an upper morpheme-to-word boundary? Does this exist as a "linguistic constant"? Are there comparative tables for different languages? Have specimen of words that actually exhaust this maximum capability of synthesis been recorded somewhere?

Comment: Some answers [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1938/482).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Citations for morpheme/word counts?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1936/citations-for-morpheme-word-counts)

Comment: I do see many more questions here than in the linked q&a-thread and my questions have not been answered there.